# Calling JSON data from Restapi in pyspark throwing Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i am trying query REST API to get a data to dataframe using pyspark.
but it is throwing error as

```
File "C:/Users/QueryRestapi.py", line 30, in <module>
    df = parse_dataframe(json_data)
  File "C:/Users/QueryRestapi.py", line 22, in parse_dataframe
    rdd = SparkContext.parallelize(mylist)

TypeError: unbound method parallelize() must be called with SparkContext instance as first argument (got list instance instead)
```

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from urllib import urlopen
import json
spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("DataCleansing") \
     .getOrCreate()


def convert_single_object_per_line(json_list):
    json_string = ""
    for line in json_list:
        json_string += json.dumps(line) + "\n"
    return json_string

def parse_dataframe(json_data):
    r = convert_single_object_per_line(json_data)
    mylist = []
    for line in r.splitlines():
        mylist.append(line)
    rdd = SparkContext.parallelize(mylist)
    df = sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd)
    return df

url = "https://"mylink"
response = urlopen(url)
data = str(response.read())
json_data = json.loads(data)
df = parse_dataframe(json_data)
```

Please help me, if i am missing something.......Thanks a lot

Comment: can you replace `SparkContext` with `spark.sparkContext.parallelize`?

Comment: @boogiewoogie, Your code works fine if you have very small data &  for big data .. it might fail with heap space issue as you are fetching entire data in driver then creating data frame .. instead of this try to check this rest data source for spark - https://github.com/sourav-mazumder/Data-Science-Extensions/tree/master/spark-datasource-rest